# How do I override the printing of arrays?

Tags: pharo

```
printOn: aStream
    | normalized |
    normalized := self normalized.
    aStream nextPut: ${.
    self isEmpty ifFalse: [ 
        normalized printElem: 1 on: aStream.
        2 to: self size do: [ :i | 
            aStream nextPutAll: ' . '.
            normalized printElem: i on: aStream 
            ].
        ].
    aStream nextPut: $}
```

This `printOn:` method works, but the Inspector is using some other route to print the array. How do I to tell the Inspector to use the above method for my class that inherits from Array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspector uses `gtDisplayOn:` to represent objects.

In `Object` it is implemented as:

```
gtDisplayOn: stream
    "This offers a means to customize how the object is shown in the inspector"
    ^ self printOn: stream
```

However, `Collection` overrides it as:

```
gtDisplayOn: stream
    self printNameOn: stream.
    stream
        space;
        nextPut: $[;
        print: self size;
        nextPutAll: (' item' asPluralBasedOn: self size);
        nextPut: $];
        space.
    self size <= self gtCollectionSizeThreshold 
        ifTrue: [ self printElementsOn: stream ]
```

Just override it again in your class to use `printOn:` as `Object` does.